# Find child domains of a URL

Tags: url, domains, subdomain

Is there a way to find all the child domains of a URL?

e.g. parent url: www.example.com

Sample child domains:

- www.a.example.com
- www.abracadabra.example.com
- www.zoo.example.com

Comment: This isn't really a programming question... perhaps it should be moved?

Answer (score 2):

Only if the DNS server allows [DNS zone Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer), which almost no servers do for security reasons.

That is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing site:websiteaddress.com in a Google search. It will let you find any subdomains that are public somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

U can use diff online services. One of them is http://www.magic-net.info/dns-and-ip-tools.dnslookup